# What object has focus?

Tags: jquery, focus

I need to know when a particular input field loses focus, what object has focus. I can do an on blur function to determine when the field loses focus, but I can't figure out how to get the ID of the object that has focus.

Basically, I have a field doing something when you're in it and I need to determine when someone has clicked into another field so it will stop doing that thing.

Something like this:

```html
<input id="field1">
<input id="field2>
```

```js
$("#field2").on("blur", function() { 
  if $(":hasfocus").id() === "field1" { 
    // do something 
  } 
});
```

What is the best way to go about this without trying to do some global focus tracker?

Response to comments:

A) An on blur doesn't actually work for this situation.   I specifically need to know the ID of the object that has focus once this one loses focus.

B) $(":focus") is something I looked at but it didn't occur to me that it would return multiple objects.  I tried $(":focus").attr("id") which always returned body, which I now realize is because it's only getting the ID of the last object in that list.   Thanks!

C) $(":focus") is returning nothing.  The array length is 0.  Not quite sure why that would be.

Comment: 'I have a field doing something when you're in it and I need to determine when someone has clicked into another field so it will stop doing that thing' - in this case attach a `blur` event handler to the element and stop doing the thing when the event occurs. There's no need to know what now has focus, only that the target element lost focus

Comment: *I have a field doing something when you're in it* - alternatively (to the above) - when you "do that thing", check if your field has focus before your activity.   Depends on the activity.  Easiest is, as above, when you get focus start, when you lose focus stop.  No need for blur/onfocus tracking.

Comment: The issue is that there's a (small) gap between when one input loses the focus and the next gains it - so within the `blur` event, there *are no elements that have focus* - only when the next element gets focus, which occurs on the next element's `focus` event.  See this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ruce0xnt/

Comment: Otherwise, see: [`:focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) - in your case: `if ($(":focus").first().attr("id") === "field1") {` to check/get the id of the focused element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the best solution was to put in another focus handler for :input.

I just check for $(":input").on("focus") and if the ID does not match my input field(s), then it completes the processing.

I have a function that replaces an input field with another set of fields for an IP address entry.  What I was trying to do is detect if someone tabbed or clicked out of my field so that I could write it back to the original input field.

The :input focus resolved that issue rather than trying to determine things when the fields I care about lose focus.